# UCBT Bluetooth Simulator

Tags: bluetooth, ns2

Can anyone please tell me if UCBT can be used for RSSI measurement and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

RSSI - Received Signal Strength Indication - measurement of the strength power of the radio signal. UCBT - University of Cincinnati Bluetooth extension for ns2 simulation software. No you cannot measure the RSSI with UCBT. You should try to use something like Wireshark for this.

Comment: thanks for the reply. according to wht i can see...wireshark is a network analyser tool. can b used for simulations also?